# On Raw HTML, website looks as I intend it. But on Django, there is some blank space created during the for loop

Tags: html, css, django

```
<div id="Project" class="bg-white fnt-white brdr project-div ">
        <div class="float-left image-for-project-container brdr">
            <img src="{% static './Images/manworking.webp' %}" alt="manworking"  height="630px">
        </div>

        
        {% for project in project_details %}
        <div class=" project-container inline-block ">
            <h2 class="text-center fnt-black head-portfolio">
                {{project.project_name}}
            </h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="margin-auto txt-portfolio roboto hover-orange fnt-black">
                {{project.project_details}}
            </p>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="buttons read-more fnt-black">Read More</a>
            
        </div>
{% endfor %}
        
        
    </div>
```

**Issue:** The project container when receiving dynamic entries from Django model, creates multiple project containers as executed by the forloop. However, as evident from the image attached, as each project container is created, it is creating an unwanted upward indentation or margin successively. What am I doing wrong?

This is the HTML code. I do not think there is any requirement for my CSS stylesheet as when I view the HTML file without Django, it's absolutely alright. I have also attached an image to show the space that is being created. In case the Imgur is not being shown here is the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnUUG.png).

Comment: Where is the closing `{% endfor %}` tag ?

Comment: @NicolasAppriou thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to type it in, tho it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline block's vertical-alignment is set to the text baseline, this is why the bottom text, the 'Read More' links line up. To make them align at the top, you will have to set vertical-align:top to the project-container class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours trying to figure this out because inspect element had shown that there was just an empty space.